# Solutions for linear equation system Ax = b

Tags: linear-algebra

Two solutions are known for the linear equation system $Ax = b$. These are (for example):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How to determine (at least) one extra solution? How to solve problems like this in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following:

$A\begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
2
\end{pmatrix} = b$ and $A\begin{pmatrix}
2  \\
1
\end{pmatrix} = b$   $\Rightarrow $ $A\begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
2
\end{pmatrix} + A\begin{pmatrix}
2  \\
1
\end{pmatrix} = 2b$  $\Rightarrow $ $A\begin{pmatrix}
3  \\
3
\end{pmatrix}=2b$ $\Rightarrow $ $A\begin{pmatrix}
3/2  \\
3/2
\end{pmatrix}=b$

Answer (score 1):

Then you have that

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
2
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
2  \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1  \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

belongs to the solution set of the associated homogeneous linear system $Ax = 0$. Hence every vector like

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
2
\end{pmatrix}
+ \lambda
\begin{pmatrix}
-1  \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

is a solution of the original system $Ax = b$ for any $\lambda$.